# How to install hadoopy package in python?

Tags: python, hadoop, hdfs, hadoopy

I'm trying to write a file to HDFS through Python Script with the below mentioned code.

```
import hadoopy
import os

hdfs_path = 'data.json'


def read_local_dir(local_path):
    for fn in os.listdir(local_path):
        path = os.path.join(local_path, fn)
        if os.path.isfile(path):
            yield path, open(path).read()


def main():
    local_path = '.'
    hadoopy.writetb(hdfs_path, read_local_dir(local_path))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

In this case, to execute the above code I'm trying to `pip install hadoopy` package in *cmd*, but installation fails. Also tried installation by downloading the *hadoopy-0.5.0.tar.gz* didn't worked. Kindly help me resolving this issue.

Error :

```
> pip install hadoopy
Collecting hadoopy
  Using cached hadoopy-0.5.0.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    running egg_info
    creating pip-egg-info\hadoopy.egg-info
    writing top-level names to pip-egg-info\hadoopy.egg-info\top_level.txt
    writing pip-egg-info\hadoopy.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info\hadoopy.egg-info\dependency_links.t
xt
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info\hadoopy.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "<Path>\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-4mzcdtzr\hadoopy\setup.
py", line 95, in <module>
        ext_modules=ext_modules)
      File "c:\python34\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "c:\python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "c:\python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line
180, in run
        self.find_sources()
      File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line
207, in find_sources
        mm.run()
      File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line
291, in run
        self.add_defaults()
      File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line
320, in add_defaults
        sdist.add_defaults(self)
      File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\sdist.py", line 125
, in add_defaults
        for _, src_dir, _, filenames in build_py.data_files:
      File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_py.py", line
59, in __getattr__
        self.data_files = files = self._get_data_files()
      File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_py.py", line
86, in _get_data_files
        file[plen:] for file in self.find_data_files(package, src_dir)
      File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_py.py", line
94, in find_data_files
        + self.package_data.get(package, []))
    TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "map") to list

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in <Path>\A
ppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-4mzcdtzr\hadoopy\
```

Thanks in Advance..!

Comment: please share the error you are getting. it will help to solve your problem

Comment: I have updated the Question with the Error i'm getting while installing Hadoopy Package.